# How to download JS appended values as a HTML file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to download appended valu as a HTML file.
here this is my code. values append from out html file through iframe.
this code working well and retrive correct value.
I just want to download that appended value as complete new HTML file

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Iframe export</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<iframe src="iframe.html" id="aaa"></iframe>

<a href="javascript:;" onclick="return aaa()" id="download">AAA</a>


<script type="text/javascript">
function aaa()
{
    var aaa=document.getElementById('aaa').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;

    $("body").append(aaa);

}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Can you please help me to resolve this problem.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dummy `<a>` tag with a `download` attribute and a [data URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs):

```
function aaa()
{
    var aaa=document.getElementById('aaa').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = "filename.html";
    link.href = "data:text/html," + aaa;
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4rm3ges0/)

Comment: What's the browser support for the `download` attribute? Thought it only worked in Chrome but maybe that's old knowledge. Also, do you have to append the dummy link to the document before being able to `click()` it?

Comment: @PeterHerdenborg Chrome, Firefox, Opera & Android. Basically no IE or Safari. Probably don't have to `appendChild` I just never checked

Answer (score -1):

```
function createDownloadLink(anchorSelector, str, fileName){
        if(window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
            var fileData = [str];
            blobObject = new Blob(fileData);
            $(anchorSelector).click(function(){
                window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blobObject, fileName);
            });
        } else {
            var url = "data:text/plain;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(str);
            $(anchorSelector).attr("download", fileName);               
            $(anchorSelector).attr("href", url);
        }
    }

    $(function () {
        var str = aaa;
        createDownloadLink("#download",str,"newsletter.html");
    });
```